# iptables packetfilter on virtual bridge

Tags: virtualization, firewall, iptables, switch

I'd like to filter packets passing through a virtual bridge on a Fedora Linux machine. I've enabled the following sysctl options as described in multiple guides:

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 1
```

If one packet gets bridged from one port to another, I expect it to be passed throug the `FORWARDING` chain of the `filter` table of ip(6)tables, but this is not the case.

Is there something which has to be configured additionally?

Manuel

Comment: I think they would appear on `INPUT`.  `FORWARDING` means routing, but bridging is equivalent to "layer 2 routing" which is switching.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case either.

Comment: Shouldn't the physdev module of iptables be used when dealing with bridges ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the ebtables/brouting.  It is part of the 2.6 kernel and can allow you to make layer 2 decisions based on layer 3 information.

http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html

I used this at a previous company to create a transparent ethernet bridge which would redirect (DNAT) specified packets to a local interface on the host.